# Removing Hash, and expireat

Tags: redis

There are 2 commands in keys I want to apply to hashes. However I can't seem to find documentation on whether or not they exists. Does anyone have a clue?

EXPIREAT - removes key after a specified unix timestamp.
* Is there a way to expire a hash after a certain time?

HDEL - deletes a field of a hash
* how do I delete the entire hash not just the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hashes itself is a key. So you can apply both EXPIREAT and DEL commands on hash.

EXPIREAT hashname -> will expire the whole hash. you can't expire a single member in hash.

DEL hashname -> will delete the whole hash.

Comment: Thanks the data type explanation in the documentation confused me when it said hashes and keys were different.